# Issue when building moqui from source

Tags: moqui

I have forked moqui, mantle & PopCommerce on github & followed the command line steps to clone & build as below.

```
git clone git@github.com:moqui/moqui.git moqui
cd moqui/runtime/
git clone git@github.com:moqui/mantle.git mantle
cd component/
git clone git@github.com:moqui/PopCommerce.git PopCommerce
cd ../.. (to the moqui directory)
gradle load
gradle run
```

I have replaced my repository name in above commands.

Accessing the framework/tools using http://localhost:8080 it displays login page (without css applied) and when clicking on Login (John Doe) button below error is displayed.

```
Status Code: 403
Exception: User [john.doe] is not authorized for View on Screen [component://webroot/screen/webroot/apps/AppList.xml]
Stacktrace:
```

and accessing PopCommerce (http://localhost:8080/popc) displays below error.

```
Status Code: 404
Exception: Could not find subscreen or transition or file/content [popc] under screen [component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml] while finding url for path [popc] under from screen [component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml]
Stacktrace:
```

I tried running the framework/tools & Popcommerce using binary distribution and it worked fine.

Is there any other steps I need to follow while build from source ?

**Update:** Error during gradle load

```
75816    [           main] INFO  pl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl  - Loaded 29 records from [file:/C:/projects/moqui_ws/moqui/runtime/base-component/example/data/ExampleZzzDemoData.xml] in 6.432 seconds
75940    [           main] INFO  pl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl  - Loading entity data from [file:/C:/projects/moqui_ws/moqui/runtime/base-component/example/data/ZzaExampleRecords.csv]
75992    [           main] WARN  .context.TransactionFacadeImpl  - Transaction rollback. The rollback was originally caused by: Error loading entity data
org.moqui.entity.EntityException: The name [exampleEmail] is not a valid field name for entity [Example]
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDefinition.convertFieldString(EntityDefinition.groovy:1048)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityValueBase.setString(EntityValueBase.groovy:274)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl$EntityCsvHandler.loadFile(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:698)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.loadSingleFile(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:283)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.internalRun(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:249)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.load(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:125)
    at org.moqui.Moqui.loadData(Moqui.java:97)
    at MoquiStart.main(MoquiStart.java:105)
75997    [           main] WARN  .context.TransactionFacadeImpl  - Transaction rollback for [Error loading entity data]. Here is the current location: 
org.moqui.BaseException: Rollback location
    at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:405)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:389)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.loadSingleFile(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:298)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.internalRun(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:249)
    at org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDataLoaderImpl.load(EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy:125)
    at org.moqui.Moqui.loadData(Moqui.java:97)
    at MoquiStart.main(MoquiStart.java:105)
76372    [           main] INFO  moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta  - Created table [ARTIFACT_HIT_BIN] for entity [moqui.server.ArtifactHitBin]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like symptoms of seed/setup data not getting loaded. Your steps look fine, they should work. Look for errors in the "gradle load" step.

Comment: There are errors related to example component in moqui.log & error.log is empty. I have updated the question with stacktrace.

Comment: As I understand it this is an error that only happens on Windows, and may be related to other errors on Windows you have filed as GitHub issues. That is the better place for this (i.e. it's not really a question which is what StackOverflow is best for).